# Building an application with "drawer" in Linux/Mac/Windows

Tags: windows, linux, user-interface, macos

I'd like to build an application with a "drawer" GUI element, like it is all over the place in Mac OS X.

Is it possible to do so in Linux/Windows? Is it possible to build it crossplatform?

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot offer a good suggestion on how to do this in Linux or Windows but drawers have fallen completely out of fashion on the Mac. For example Mail and Preview which were the canonical examples of using drawers don't use them anymore (since Leopard I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like OS X drawers, but they are not used nearly as often as they used to be.  The only apps that I currently use that makes use of them are OmniWeb and TextMate.

I don't think it's worth trying to recreate that UI feature for Windows or Linux.  In addition to being too much work, your users likely will find it jarring.

Generally speaking, a standard sidebar ought to support whatever you might use a drawer for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to roll your own drawer in Linux/Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You all say that drawer is not in use "anymore", which doesn't really help. In any case, I see it fit on a TextMate perfectly, and noone complains about it :-)

Comment: Actually, I believe TextMate is moving away from the drawer to the inline project list provided by the Project Plus plugin. Moving the UI inline would work a lot better for porting to Linux and Windows as well as it would work better for maximised windows.

Answer (score 1):

KDE seems to have a drawers-like functionality as seen in [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/graphics/screenshots/3.4/qmreload.png), and some other applications (Kate, the editor, uses them too), but I have never tried to use them in anything I've written, and so would have no idea how to write them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Osx a lot, but cant just a normal sidebar do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Drawers are no long really used on the Mac. I only know of a few that still use them and most of these are older applications. Most have moved the sidebar into the app in a collapsable split view.